# ¿Qué quiere decir "Yo que vos me iría rajando"? ¿Se usa solamente en el dialecto rioplatense?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, argentina, uruguay

En la película uruguaya *La noche de 12 años* aparece el siguiente diálogo:

> —Por qué seguís lavando?
>
> —Para los que vengan.
>
> ***—Yo que vos me iría rajando.***

La traducción al inglés de la última oración era la siguiente:

> If I were you, I would get moving.

1. Si esta traducción es correcta, ¿esa última oración significaría lo mismo que la siguiente construcción?

> Si yo estuviera en tu lugar, me iría rajando.

2. ¿Se usa frecuentemente esa construcción gramatical?
3. ¿Se usa tanto en Hispanoamérica como en España? ¿O puede pertenecer más al dialecto rioplatense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente, en el español rioplatense esta construcción es sumamente usual. No obstante, leo [en esta publicación](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/yo-que-tu-leo-este-articulo/) que la construcción también se usa en otros países, y que en España y algunos otros lugares se usaría la variante "yo de + sustantivo/pronombre":

> Dentro de estos tipos de construcciones condicionales, encontramos la expresión lexicalizada —es decir, que forma una unidad que es parte de la lengua— «yo que + pronombre»: yo que tú, yo que vos, yo que él…, como en *Yo que tú no salgo sin paraguas; Yo que vos no lo meditaba tanto; Yo que él ya la hubiera dejado*. Asimismo, el segundo pronombre puede ser reemplazado por un grupo nominal «yo que + grupo nominal»: *Yo que el alcalde aprovecharía la propuesta.*
>
> Estas expresiones poseen un verdadero carácter condicional que puede desdoblarse haciendo uso de la partícula *si* acompañada del verbo *ser* en subjuntivo: *si yo fuera tú, si yo fuera vos, si yo fuera él: Si yo fuera tú, no salgo sin paraguas; Si yo fuera vos, no lo meditaba tanto; Si yo fuera él, ya la hubiera dejado; Si yo fuera el alcalde, aprovecharía la propuesta.*
>
> En el español peninsular, así como en varias zonas del español americano —sobre todo en el área caribeña— se registran las variantes *yo de ti, yo de vos, yo de él*… como equivalentes a *yo que tú* y a sus respectivas variables: *Yo de ti no me caso así me paguen; Yo de él salgo sin pedir permiso; Yo de usted ya me hubiera ido.* Sin embargo, la Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009, 3598, 47.11p) no recomienda este uso.

Comment: "Yo de" se usa en algunas zonas de España, pero la forma más común sigue siendo "yo que". https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/yo-de-ti-yo-que-tu-206/

Answer (score 1):

Casi en Todo México usamos la palabra **"rajarse"** para indicar que alguien recula o **"se echa para atrás"** (se arrepiente). Así tenemos expresiones como "No seas rajón" (No seas cobarde o no te arrepientas). No he visto la película que dices, pero en el contexto creo que si se podría traducir como "If I were you, I would get moving".

Comment: La pregunta es sobre la construcción gramatical «yo que...». El OP claramente conoce la palabra «rajar» ya que la usa en su traducción alternativa.